# Url Encoding Issue - Special Characters originate webserver crash

Tags: java, html, http, web, url-encoding

I have been searching about this info but since I'm new to web development the answers I'm getting are getting me even more confused. 
Basically, I have a webserver established in a Java Modem (which uses 1.3IDE) which will handle requests. These requests were being processed as long as I kept it simple.

```
http://87.103.87.59/teste.html?a=10&b=10
```

This request is normally processed.
However, when applying the real deal, my webserver is crashing.

```
http://5.43.52.4/api.html?ATCOMMAND=AT%5EMTXTUNNEL=SMS,0035111111111,string sending test
```

The problem is due to two aspects. The "%" character and the string sending test. 
To put everything clear, handlers I'm using are these:

```
public InputStream is = null;
private OutputStream os = null;
private byte buffer[] = new byte[];
String streamAux="";


is = socketX.openInputStream();
os = socketX.openOutputStream();
if ((is.available()>0)||(blockX==true))
{   

//Read data sent from remote client 
numDadosLidos=is.read(buffer);
for (int i=0;i<numDadosLidos;i++)
streamAux= streamAux + (char)buffer[i];  //where the url will be stored
```

Basically I will need those parameters so I can use them to operate my Java device so, I think I'll need to do some sort of encoding but there's a lot of information that I can't comprehend and my 1.3 IDE is kind of keeping me stuck.

I apologize for some sort of newbie behaviour in advance.

Hope you can lend me a hand,

Thanks

Comment: This reminds me of an issue we found in the Jetty implementation: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/570, which server do you use?

Comment: A simple server established with a socket in which I pass the required parameters to set a GPRS connection using the Java Modem SIM Card.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I basically went around the issue obliging the message to be sent using '-' character. It doesn't solve the issue, it simply solves the question with the "not-ideal" method.

Still totally interested if someone figures this one out.
Thanks.

Comment: For both (percent and space)? Spaces in URIs are never allowed and need to be translated to either `+` or `%20` - see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396 chapter 2.4.3.